# i was running the code PIP INSTALL PLATSOUND and this error was found and when i was running PIP INSTALL FLASK the code run successful

Tags: python, pip

```
PS D:\100 day python> pip install playsound
Collecting playsound
  Using cached playsound-1.3.0.tar.gz (7.7 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [28 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\aadit\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "C:\Users\aadit\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\aadit\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\aadit\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-_apbfavu\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 325, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\aadit\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-_apbfavu\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 295, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "C:\Users\aadit\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-_apbfavu\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 480, in run_setup
          super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend, self).run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
        File "C:\Users\aadit\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-_apbfavu\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 311, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 6, in <module>
        File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.2032.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\inspect.py", line 1262, in getsource    
          lines, lnum = getsourcelines(object)
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.2032.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\inspect.py", line 1244, in getsourcelines
          lines, lnum = findsource(object)
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.2032.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\inspect.py", line 1081, in findsource   
          raise OSError('could not get source code')
      OSError: could not get source code
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

I was trying to run `PLAYSOUND` to run MP3 file

Comment: First you need to do this `py -m pip install --no-deps playsound --upgrade`

Comment: [pip install playsound no longer works](https://github.com/TaylorSMarks/playsound/issues/150)

Answer (score -3):

Try upgrading pip
Installing playsound library directly from its github repository.
Perhaps there are missing dependacies or a compatibilty issue

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).